# How to do JSON String to Java Object mapping when JSON has a non-conventional format?

Tags: java, json

I want to convert JSON (which I am fetching from DB CLOB and later to String in code) to a java object. The problem is, JSON is not conventional to directly convert into an object using GSON or Jackson.

JSON Format:

```
{
  "Provider Information>>Address Line 1":"123 Street Road",
  "Provider Information>>Address Line 2":"Some road",
  "Practitioner Information>>Email":"testuser@gmail.com",
  "Practitioner Information>>DOB":"03/11/1990",
 }
```

There are only 2 sections to JSON like the above **"Provider Information"** & **"Practitioner Information"** and the total fields are around 20 for each section.

And their respective java classes - `ProviderInformation.java` & `PractitionerInformation.java`
which are having its respective fields:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProviderInformation{
   private String addressLine1;
   private String addressLine2;
   .....
}
```

And similarly,

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PractitionerInformation{
  private String email;
  private String dob;
  ...
}
```

One solution I can think of is to read each section's values into a map - one for the provider, one for the practitioner, and then for each entry - match the key to a hardcoded enum value (like having an enum for fields of each section) and then use setter methods to assign values to the object.

But that looks a little complicated to me and I wanted to know if anything simpler is available to map these fields. I have no control over incoming data to change any format.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's an unfortunate problem to have. My coworker and I discussed your problem at length and decided the best solution would be a [custom deserializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) that wraps the answer from @Koray.

Answer (score 2):

POJO classes for your JSON data, ProviderInformation and PractitionerInformation, with the respective fields.

```
public class ProviderInformation {
    @JsonProperty("Provider Information>>Address Line 1")
    private String addressLine1;

    @JsonProperty("Provider Information>>Address Line 2")
    private String addressLine2;
}

public class PractitionerInformation {
    @JsonProperty("Practitioner Information>>Email")
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty("Practitioner Information>>DOB")
    private String dob;
}
```

Use the `ObjectMapper` class from Jackson to deserialize your JSON string to Java objects

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ProviderInformation providerInfo = mapper.readValue(jsonString, ProviderInformation.class);
PractitionerInformation practitionerInfo = mapper.readValue(jsonString, PractitionerInformation.class);
```